# I want to use a variable to specify rows <tr> in a table

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a table and wish to find specific rows by inserting a variable such as /tr[i]/ where i is the row I'm after.

If I hardwire the  element in my code, it works fine:

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody[@class='sample']/tr[2]/td[2]/button/img").get_attribute("src")
```

I get the "src" attribute as expected.

But if I use a variable to examine the row of interest, I get an error:

```
i = 2
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody[@class='sample']/tr[i]/td[2]/button/img").get_attribute("src")
```

returns error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//tbody[@class='sample']/tr[i]/td[2]/button/img"`}

I code very rarely but I know I've used variables for /tr[i]/ before.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks to @Tim...worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the formatting f-string and curly braces to use the value `i`

```
i = 2
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//tbody[@class='sample']/tr[{i}]/td[2]/button/img").get_attribute("src")
```